# Why are ringtone-songs I buy from Google Play impossible to make into ringtones?

Tags: music, ringtone

This is *not* a duplicate question --- at least not a duplicate of many questions that the search-engine gave me that *seem* similar up-front -- but as soon as I read them, I realized that they do not even *address* my question.

My situation is fairly simple --- I purchased a ringtone-song on Google Play -- and was hoping to set it as my ringtone.

When I went to settings and tried to select a ringtone -- the one I had bought and downloaded wasn't available. But that's not when my frustration hit the roof.

Next, I hit the '+' sign in the upper left-hand corner -- and it asked me what app I wanted to use. I tried this three times - one for each of the three apps they offered to carry out this option with.

Here's what really irritated me ---- each of those apps (including Google Play) I got the same-old same-old pre-installed songs available ---- no way at *all* to got to the track that I paid good money for!!!

What am I to do? Is there a bloody way that the song I paid for in order to set as a ringtone can *possibly* be set as my ringtone?

Comment: No offense meant, but are you sure you saw all [related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=ringtone+google+play)?

Comment: Is it listed in Play Music or can you find that file in a file explorer app?

Comment: @Lucky - I can not find it in the file explorer app. The song _is_ downloaded - but I have no idea where to (and since it _is_ advertised as a ringtone there needs to be _some_ way to solve this). So how do I get it to download to somewhere that I _can_ find it?

Comment: @Firelord - Well -- if I didn't, it wasn't for lack of effort on my part. That said, I will look at the list of questions you just linked to --- and whether I find something that answers my question or not, I will report back here to let you know.

Comment: Are you sure it is not in the Downloads list? Can you share the link of the play store item which you bought?

Comment: @Firelord ---- I am looking --- I find a *number* of questions that *seem* to be similar ---- but which upon reading them, are either (a) different in a key point (b) their solution does not work (c) the system does not give me opportunity to _apply_ said solution. Not really that surprising --- since some of those questions are a good few years old --- and at the rate technology changes, they have lost relevance. Would be nice if Stack Exchange found a way to treat aspects of technology that change like the stairs of Hogwarts differently from those that remain _relatively_ static over time.

Comment: @Lucky - Here it is: [link](https://play.google.com/music/m/Bbivxilx7kbcupvwnsoky72xlay?t=Top_60s_Tv_Themes_-_TV_Star_Ringtones)

Comment: @Lucky - Actually [I think this is the correct link](https://play.google.com/music/m/Txkzarpperbtipylodpwioyu3bm?t=Doctor_Who_-_TV_Star_Ringtones)

Comment: @user3080003 Please follow this link on [How to download and manage your Google Play Music on your device and computer?](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1250232?hl=en)

Comment: @Lucky ----- the directions you directed to direct me to things that I had already done (to no avail) before even asking the question this discussion is over. I did the whole thing of actually *downloading* the song to my device. I still am completely unable to access it from any dialogue that supposedly allows me to add ringtones.